# Make IE play well, and testing it

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, testing, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I do not want to exclude Internet Explorer users.  I would like to provide them with an experience similar to other browsers.  There are various compatibility shims around and I would like to know what is the "new kid in town" and do it right.  I don't want to go to the hacking side.

Here are some I found:

- html5shiv: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/
- html5.js: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/
- IE7: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Are there others I have missed?  I would like to include one file, and have 90% of IE bugs go away.  My question is: what single .js file can do the trick, as of 2012?

Given that, how can I test it properly on a mac?

Thanks in advance.

Follow-up: I discovered and tested: https://saucelabs.com/; it looks nice... as good as vnc on my pc.

Comment: You do realise that html5shiv, html5.js and ie7-js are all "turning to the hacking side", right?

Comment: It's all hacking at the end of the day,  modernizer isn't 'one script' but I'm pretty sure it includes all the above and more.

Comment: As for testing on a mac, if you have a real PC, but are too lazy too move, just remote desktop to it :)

Comment: i dont know modernizer, and after scanning the site, i am not sure it a one trick poney, you have to know what your patching to use it... is it better than ie7.js ? no idea after ready many many pages on the site